# Why choose LuaLaTeX over XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, luatex

There are questions on TeX.sX already about what the differences between LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX are ([Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex)), what one should be keep in mind when going from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX ([Considerations when migrating from XeTeX to LuaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23598/considerations-when-migrating-from-xetex-to-luatex)), and how they typically differ in their preambles ([Frequently loaded packages: Differences between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87155/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-xelatex-and-lualatex)).

From the perspective of an end user, however, I've yet to see any reason for why one should switch from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. That is, I have read facts like LuaLaTeX using the Lua scripting engine, but that is not relevant to an end user like me who has no idea what that entails.

Yet I've noticed that most of the cool kids here on TeX.sX seem to prefer LuaLaTeX over XeLaTex, and I'm curious what those reasons are, and more specifically, if they apply to "normal" end users like myself.

To give LuaLaTeX a try, I recompiled an old short handout of mine in LuaLaTex, and they mostly looked exactly the same. Where they differed, however, XeLaTeX clearly gave the better results. Below are some examples I found in my handout:

XeLaTeX:

[image]

LuaLaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
    [
        Path = C:/Windows/Fonts/,
        Extension = .otf,
        UprightFont = LinLibertine_R,
        BoldFont = LinLibertine_RZ,
        ItalicFont = LinLibertine_RI,
        BoldItalicFont = LinLibertine_RZI
    ]{libertine}

\begin{document}
mak\textbf{\underline{a}}t
\textit{wund\textbf{\underline{V\char"0306}}de}
\textit{*wund\textbf{\underline{\char"014D}}d\char"0113}
\end{document}
```

In the second and third word, LuaLaTeX adds more white space before the underlined italicized boldfaced characters. In my view, it adds too much. Notice, however, that it does not add any extra white space in the first word, where the character is not italicized.

In the second word, XeLaTeX handles the placement of the combining breve character well, but LuaLaTeX does not. This is potentially a worry, since I normally use a lot of combining characters in my documents (this being the only example in my handout).

If anything, I only see reasons to stick to XeLaTeX for the moment, but I am still curious if there are advantages to LuaLaTeX over XeLaTeX that could potentially override the disadvantages I've identified above.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that lualatex uses dynamic memory management. As author of a memory-intensive package, I believe that this is quite interesting and simplifies things considerably. I suppose the xelatex has the typical cumbersome memory limit restrictions.

Comment: To some extent, the problem you note has to do with the font:  your example gives perfect results in `lualatex` with Brill, DejaVu, Heuristica, and Source Sans Pro, all of which have the `mkmk` feature (Junicode also has it, but the output is ugly).

Comment: @Thérèse I think you mean ``mark`` (``mkmk`` is for aligning diacritics to other diacritics)? So the question is why ``\textit{\textbf{V\char"0306}}`` gives a good result with ``XeLaTeX``, but not with ``LuaLaTeX``.

Comment: The four fonts with which your example gave good results in `lualatex` have both the `mark` and the `mkmk` feature.  I don’t know which is responsible for the good result (I’ve also seen some fonts with an `abvm` feature, and I’ve never tried to work out how font designers interpret each of these).  But at least it’s clear that the differences between `xetex` and `luatex` aren’t the only factor; the font also plays a role.

Comment: @Thérèse I've opened a new question about this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184758/combining-diacritical-mark-is-misaligned-with-luatex-but-not-with-xetex

Comment: @Christian, What about context, does it use dynamic memory management?

Comment: @skan context mk IV does (because it relies on luatex).

Comment: See also: [lua - What is a simple example of something you can do with LuaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70/what-is-a-simple-example-of-something-you-can-do-with-luatex)

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I've been using XeLaTeX on some large documents (500+ pages or fairly complex text using 116 packages) and have not run across any memory limits. Are these limits more evident when processing certain types of text (eg math)?

Answer (score 59):

In my personal opinion (i.e. from anecdotal situations I've encountered), `lua(la)tex` looks indeed a little less stable than `xe(la)tex`, in particular when it comes to some advanced font features (`fontspec` was after all developed for `xe(la)tex` first). It's somehow to be expected: `xe(la)tex` itself is older than `lua(la)tex` and can therefore expected to be a more mature in terms of bugs, etc.

The advantages I see of `lua(la)tex` though are:

- `lua(la)tex` has been choosen as the official successor of `pdf(la)tex`, so you can expect more development effort to go towards it now and in the future. For example, `microtype` supports much more features under `lua(la)tex` than it does under `xe(la)tex`,
- `lua(la)tex` opens up the internals of TeX to the Lua programming language. This might sound like some irrelevant technicality to the end user, but in reality it is not when you consider that this might enable advanced packages / features that are just not possible to implement otherwise, such as rivers detection and most other features of [`impnattypo`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo).
- `lua(la)tex` doesn't rely on system-specific libraries, so in theory you're less prone to encounter platform-specific issues or differences in output.

Comment: Official successor? What about LaTeX 3; different discussion?

Comment: @Raphael I believe you are mistaking _engines_ for _formats_

Comment: @cgnieder I see. I always thought that LaTeX 3 would include a new compiler.

Comment: XeTeX relies on system specefic libraries for system specific features (like locating system fonts, which is always system specific, if you want to do it reliably), so it is hardly an issue in practice.

Comment: On my computer Lua takes much more time to compile than Xe

Comment: I realize this is a very late comment, but for others who may come here in search of diffs between xe and lua: XeTeX correctly renders Indic scripts, whereas afaict, LuaTeX does not (even as of the 2017 TeXLive distro).  There's a post here with more details: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285527/how-can-bengali-v-2-bng2-be-used-to-typeset-bengali-with-xetex (and a comment from me at the end).  This may also affect other complex scripts, like Burmese.

Comment: @MikeMaxwell Hmm. We have already combined pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX, and even included all of ConTeXt into the fold. Yes, there are holes in LuaTeX (where pdfTeX functionality is concerned). I would use XeTeX, since it has a lot less holes (still has some). We haven't yet rewritten our engine in C, but we are still satisfied with TeX macros performance. You can do a whole lot of programming in XeTeX as of now. Lua, without a compiler to faster codes, is a show-stopper for us. In short, there is currently no viable reason (for typsetting purposes) to choose LuaTeX over XeTeX.

Answer (score 23):

I agree with Xavier on the first two points.

Another advantage of LuaTeX over XeTeX is that LuaTeX uses the PDF engine of pdfTeX, while XeTeX uses its own one. One consequence of this is, that all features of the PGF graphics package (on which TikZ builds) should be available also under LuaTeX, while some features are definitely not available under XeTeX.

Comment: Can you give an example of a PGF feature that does not work under XeTeX?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Shading is the most common example I think, try for example `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` with `pdflatex` and then with `xelatex`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I see no difference between the outputs produced by `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. I otherwise agree with Faheem, and it's hard to evaluate the validity of Wolfang's claim without at least one example.

Comment: @Sverre You're right that there is no difference *now*, but there have definitely been problems earlier, see e.g. [TikZ 3.0.0 (release) produces strange shadings if used with XeLaTeX and standalone](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151524) I think there were problems prior to `pgf` 3.0  as well, but cannot say for sure. There have also been other problems, e.g. [TikZ example involving Spies won't typeset properly using XeLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33260) I'd say Wolfgang's claim was perfectly valid at the time, but most of these problems may have been fixed since, though I don't know

Comment: It looks like [copying PNG files instead of recoding](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327011/15107) is a feature not supported by `xetex`.

Comment: Which one compiles the document faster?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Search for `xetex` in the pgfmanual. Version 3.1.4b says that it does not support masking with `xelatex` and no image inclusion with `xetex`/plain tex. Yeah... and on top, most graph layouting does not work (it is implemented in Lua).

Answer (score 23):

Since I am a heavy user of `tikz/pgf`, here are some key points why I always prefer `lualatex`.

- `pgfplots` works best with `lualatex`. On a moderate size `csv` file, both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` run out of memory.
- TikZ `graphdrawing` library works only with `lualatex`. The layout algorithms are implemented in Lua; they are too complicated to be implemented in TeX.
- Access to `Lua` (though I wish it was python) means a lot if you are doing very non-standard things e.g. read only n lines from a csv before plotting it; replace 'X' with 'Y', write to file etc. These are non-standard use cases but they are better handled in `Lua` than using some latex package.

Probably it is safe to say that whatever you can do in `XeLatex`, you can do with `lualatex` but not the other way round (*See comments below*).

Comment: @Mico You're right, I forgot about the command line options.

Comment: @Dilawar - I agree with all of your statements except the last one, *viz.*, that "whatever one can do in XeLaTeX, one can do with LuaLaTeX". See, e.g., the posting [Can one set a specific font variant in xelatex for uppercase letters only?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33855/5001) While it may be true, in a very narrow sense, that it *should* be possible to replicate the functionality of the `\XeTeXcharclass`/ `\XeTeXinterchartoks` machinery in LuaTeX, this replication still has to be performed. For sure, I'm not aware of any LuaLaTeX packages that provide this type of functionality.

Comment: Also, xelatex can use [`PSTricks`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks), but lualatex cannot.

Answer (score 11):

LuaTeX including METAPOST as `mplib` is a huge advantage (this allows one to directly use MP code w/o the overhead and need to pause typesetting, run a separate process and then load the created file) --- looking forward to LuaTeX maturing past the difficulties noted in the question.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you elaborated on _how_ it is a "huge advantage" that luatex includes "METAPOST as `mplib`". I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 8):

One good reason to switch to LuaTeX is the fact that XeTeX can't use the glyph names for glyphs in the Private Use Area of fonts. As a result, any glyph from the PUA will end up as garbled text if you try to copy it from the pdf output. This issue has been raised in [Small-caps, old-style numbers, and some ligatures produce odd symbols in PDF copy text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49502/small-caps-old-style-numbers-and-some-ligatures-produce-odd-symbols-in-pdf-cop) and [\pdfglyphtounicode with XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110354/pdfglyphtounicode-with-xetex). I don't know if this is likely to be resolved, since the XeTeX maintainers apparently insist that fonts shouldn't use the PUA at all. But as long as there are many characters that haven't been included in Unicode yet, fonts need to add those extra characters in the PUA.

LuaTeX doesn't have this problem, it seems. LuaTeX does not, however, as seen in the OP's question, deal very well with many other aspects of font outputs ...

Comment: Using PUA for glyphs that should be accessed with font features is not the same as using PUA for unencoded characters, the later works as intended; PUA in → PUA out.

Comment: @KhaledHosny I don't know much about this, but if a font has e.g. both lining and old style numbers, is there any other place to put the old style numbers than in the PUA? They can't both occupy the Unicode slots for numbers. Similarly, if a font has ligatures that haven't been assigned to Unicode yet - can they go anywhere but the PUA?

Comment: The recommended way is to not give the alternate glyphs any Unicode points at all, that is what all the new fonts does. And if the font designer does this and give them proper glyph names, everything works as expected.

Comment: @KhaledHosny So the problem is not that they are in PUA (could they be somewhere else?), but that they have been assigned Unicode points? Could you give an example of a (free) font that behaves like this? I would like to see what it means that a font has characters without Unicode points. When I look at the fonts I have, they all use Unicode points for old style figures, custom ligatures, etc.

Comment: PUA *are* Unicode code points, Unicode just does not assign any characters to them. Check latest version of JUnicode font of how variant glyphs should be handled (or my Amiri font, it has 5000+ variant glyphs, non is assigned any code point).

Comment: Ok, I'm beginning to understand. When I look at the Junicode ligature ``fft`` in BabelMap, it says that ``Code points`` is 0000, whereas the ``Code point`` for the ``Sample Glyph`` is EECE. If I use ``\char"EECE`` in XeTeX, I get the fft ligature, but is garbled when I copy from the pdf. If I just type ``fft``, on the other hand, I get the same ligature, but I can copy it out as ``fft``. In Linux Libertine, the same ligature has ``Code points`` 0020, and has ``Sample Glyph Code point`` E035. This ligature is garbled out of the pdf no matter if I use ``\char"E035`` or just type ``fft``.

Comment: But actually, I see that _all_ Junicode glyphs have ``0000`` in their ``Sample Glyph Code point``, so I'm not sure if this means anything. In the end, I am curious where I can see that the "bad" fonts like Libertine are doing something different with their glyphs than "good" fonts like Junicode.

Comment: I don’t know BabelMap, so I don’t understand its terminology. Junicode used to use PUA for its ligatures and alternate glyphs, but last version(s) does not do that any more. The PUA glyphs are still left for backward compatibility e.g. for people who were typing the PUA codes directly (which is one if the reason why PUA should *not* be used for this; it encourages bad practices). Libertine is still using PUA, though I discussed this with its author and hopefully it will be fixed in later releases.

Comment: Does that mean that if I view a "good" font in any character viewing software, I simply won't find the ligatures/old style numbers that are created in the "correct" way? Because really, I have looked at some fonts like Junicode, and the only place I can find such glyphs are in the PUA.

Comment: Yes, unless you are using a *font* viewer (or glyph palette, in applications that has such a thing).

Comment: I see. BabelMap doesn't show unencoded glyphs, but FontForge does.

Answer (score 5):

Adding in a comment on write streams, since they matter a lot for larger projects. In short, write streams are the amount of concurrent open files for writing (XXX)TeX can have, and varies a bit between different implementations. If you have used all your write slots, there are packages such as `morewrites` which uses one of the files as cache for opening more files, therefore slowing down matters since a lot of files of opened and closed.

In large works, such as books or theses, the limited amount of writes in Xe(La)TeX (16 write streams) requires the use of libraries such as `morewrites` to function properly (multiple glossaries, indices etc have a tendency to eat write streams). Lua(La)Tex has 256 write streams and therefore does not require extra overhead such as `morewrites` to handle large projects.

The largest issue with `morewrites` (i.e. under XeLaTeX) is the performance of your drive, since you have to open and close files constantly you get a large performance penalty (i.e. waiting for IO). If you are using a machine controlled by the department's IT division you might also have anti-virus and similar scanning all the file reads (!).

As an example my PhD-thesis (~400 pages with figures, tables, glossaries, and auto-generated content by external scripts) compiles from clean checkout in ~8 minutes with LuaLaTeX and ~24 minutes with XeLaTeX on my department laptop, all due to `morewrites` opening and closing files constantly and additional overhead from "forced" anti-virus programs. On my workstation at home the numbers are 90 seconds for LuaLaTeX vs 220 seconds for XeLaTeX with RAM-disk and scanning disabled for project directories.

As such, for me the implicit differences, such as write streams, are more important than the actual implementation differences between XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a line or two at the beginning explaining what "write streams" are?

Comment: @Sverre Added a bit more, enough?