# Combine Type1 and OpenType libertine fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, libertine, opentype, type1

I would like to use the Type1 `libertine` fonts provided by the package [`libertine`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine/) and compile with `XeLaTeX`. According to the manual under section 4, this can be activated with the option `type1`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[type1, oldstyle]{libertine}
\begin{document}
This is a test 1234567890 fi ffi fl ffl ft fft fj ffj tt
\end{document}
```

I would like to use the OpenType fonts, also provided by the `libertine` package, when I need to access glyphs not included in the Type1 fonts. As mentioned in section 5 in the manual, I can access these with the macro `\libertineGlyph{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\libertineGlyph{uni025D}
\end{document}
```

But how do I combine these? As said above, I'd like to stick to Type1 fonts as far as possible (as this renders ligatures and old style numbers copy- and searchable in the pdf), but switch to the OpenType fonts when I need special glyphs. Combining the `type1` option with `\libertineGlyph{}` does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[type1, oldstyle]{libertine}
\begin{document}
This is a test 1234567890 fi ffi fl ffl ft fft fj ffj tt \libertineGlyph{uni025D}
\end{document}
```

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> l.4 ...ffi fl ffl ft fft fj ffj tt \libertineGlyph{uni025D}?

Comment: It appears that `\libertineGlyph` is now only defined when the `type1` option is not used.  Why do you need to use it?

Comment: @Thruston That's mentioned twice in my question: (1) "I would like to use the OpenType fonts [...] when I need to access glyphs not included in the Type1 fonts" (2) "I'd like to [...] switch to the OpenType fonts when I need special glyphs".

Comment: OK I see.  It's just that your example compiles fine here if I remove the `type1` option. But I guess there are other glyphs you need.

Comment: Actually no.  What I meant was why not use the OTF for everything?  Do the Type 1 fonts have any glyph in them that's not in the OTF?

Comment: @Thruston Ah. Actually, the reason for wanting to use Type1 fonts whenever possible is given in my question as well: "this renders ligatures and old style numbers copy- and searchable in the pdf" ``:P``

Comment: The ligatures and old-style numbers from the OpenType fonts _are_ copyable and searchable.  The only times I’ve had trouble were when a font’s designer misused the Private Use Area for ligatures.

Comment: @Thérèse Which is the case with the libertine font ... I'm not speaking about OpenType fonts in general.

Comment: I tried Herbert’s example with no problem; which ligatures are giving you trouble?

Comment: @Thérèse Are you compiling with ``XeLaTeX`` as mentioned in my question? Problems with: Th, 1234567890, ft, fft, fj, ffj, tt.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change from my default, `luatex`.  `Xetex` does produce a complete mess here, while `luatex` gets it right.  Is `luatex` an option for you?

Comment: @Thérèse Eventually, yes, but it's not mature enough yet. As an example, the problem of using combining diacritics addressed in [Why choose LuaLaTeX over XeLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126206/why-choose-lualatex-over-xelatex) still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to combine definitions from libertine.sty:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter
  \def\libertine@base{LinLibertine}
  \def\biolinum@base{LinBiolinum}
  \defaultfontfeatures{
     Ligatures = TeX ,
     Extension = .otf ,
     SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps} ,
  }
  \newfontfamily\libertine
        [ Numbers = {Proportional,OldStyle},
          UprightFont    = *_R,
          ItalicFont     = *_RI,
          BoldFont       = *_RB, 
          BoldItalicFont = *_RBI,
        ] {\libertine@base}
  \def\lib@fxl{LinLibertine_R}
  \def\lib@fxb{LinBiolinum_R}
  \def\lib@fxk{LinBiolinum_K}
  \def\lib@fxi{LinLibertine_I}

  \providecommand*\DeclareTextGlyphY[3]{%
      % \DeclareTextGlyphY{fxl}{s_t}{64262}
      % #1=basefont #2=glyphname, #3=position
      \def\lib@temp{#1}%
      \ifx\lib@temp\lib@fxl \@namedef{#1@#2}{{\libertine\char#3\relax}}\else%
        \ifx\lib@temp\lib@fxb \@namedef{#1@#2}{{\biolinum\char#3\relax}}\else%
          \ifx\lib@temp\lib@fxk \@namedef{#1@#2}{{\biolinumkey\char#3\relax}}\else%
            \ifx\lib@temp\lib@fxi \@namedef{#1@#2}{{\libertineInitial\char#3\relax}}\else%
      \fi\fi\fi\fi}
  %
  \input{LinLibertine_R}
  \input{LinBiolinum_R}
  \input{LinBiolinum_K}
  \input{LinLibertine_I}
  %
  \DeclareRobustCommand*\libertineGlyph[1]{\@nameuse{LinLibertine_R@#1}}
  \DeclareRobustCommand*\biolinumGlyph[1]{\@nameuse{LinBiolinum_R@#1}}
  \DeclareRobustCommand*\biolinumKeyGlyph[1]{\@nameuse{LinBiolinum_K@#1}}
  \DeclareRobustCommand*\libertineInitialGlyph[1]{\@nameuse{LinLibertine_I@#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1,oldstyle]{libertine}
\begin{document}

This is a test 1234567890 fi ffi fl ffl ft fft fj ffj tt

{\libertine\libertineGlyph{uni025D}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add some words about what you're doing here, and how/why it works? Also, adding ``\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`` removes many of the ligatures included in my test line.

Comment: I took elements from libertine.sty that support \libertineGlyph. You can use LY1 encoding if you want.

Comment: or OT1, which seems to give all the ligatures in your test line.

Comment: ``OT1`` provides the highest number of ligatures, but it doesn't contain any characters used outside of English, so that's not really an option. I'm curious why ``\usepackage{fontenc}`` is necessary at all. It's not needed when just loading ``\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}``.

Comment: You need fontenc to define \newfontfamily, which is needed to load the otf font.

Comment: Sorry, I confused fontenc and fontspec. fontenc is needed to undo the font-encoding setting by fontspec. If you \usepackage{libertine} without fontenc or fontspec, you're getting the default encoding (OT1).

Comment: Really? When I compile your code without ``fontenc``, my output has the Latin Modern font rather than libertine.

Comment: Look at the log to see why.

Comment: @Sverre Probably because it cannot switch to libertine with the EU1 encoding active so it falls back to the default which is Latin Modern if `fontspec` is loaded. Note that you should still get libertine for the glyph following the `\libertine` command but the *default* font hasn't been changed in that case.

Answer (score 2):

All glyphs from Type1 are in the OpenType. There is no need to use the Type1 version of Libertine:

```
\documentclass{article}% xelatex or lualatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[oldstyle]{libertine}
\begin{document}

This is a test 1234567890 fi ffi fl ffl ft fft fj ffj tt

\symbol{"025D}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, all the glyphs are included in the OpenType fonts, but ligatures and oldstyle numbers won't be copy- and searchable, as mentioned in my question.

Comment: "won't be copy- and searchable"  Which pdf viewer are you using?

Comment: @user51830 Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: "won't be copy- and searchable"  What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I have no problem with searching except the oldstyle figures which are always lined one when copied.

Comment: Did you try witn XeLaTeX? I get a mess... (And it would be better if it *did* copy the figures as lined but the issue with the ligatures is even worse.)