# Combining diacritical mark is misaligned with luatex, but not with xetex

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, libertine, luaotfload

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont = {* Semibold Italic}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\textit{\textbf{V\char"0306}}
\end{document}
```

Why does this give the correct output with `XeLaTeX`, but not with `LuaLaTeX`?

XeLaTeX:

[image]

LuLaTeX:

[image]

(This question is a spin-off from [Why choose LuaLaTeX over XeLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126206/why-choose-lualatex-over-xelatex))

Comment: Really seems like a bug somewhere.

Comment: The output is perfect with Brill, CharisSIL, DejaVu, Heuristica, and Source Sans Pro, all of which have the `mark` and `mkmk` features.  Junicode has these features but fails the test.  Amiri has the `mark` but not the `mkmk` feature, and also fails this test.  I haven’t found a font without these features which produces the desired output in `luatex`.

Comment: The `mkmk` should not have any rule here since there are no mark to mark interaction involved. depending on how the font is built, you might not also need the `mark` feature to get correct output.

Comment: I also tried combining chinese, persian and russian in one document. I wasn't for anything, tried it just for fun, so when it didn't work, I just quit. But LuaLaTeX produced only whitespace instead of chinese, while XeLaTeX produced empty boxes. I guess better support and bug fixes will be present in future. Maybe, better version of LuaTeX will be in TeX Live 17.

Comment: `closed as unclear what you're asking` What? It's obvious! LuaTeX does it wrong while XeTeX is doing it correctly. What is the reason for that difference. There is no possibility how a question can be more clear that this one.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is fixed with Libertinus Serif (a fork of Linux Libertine).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldItalicFont = {* Semibold Italic}]{Libertinus Serif}
\begin{document}
\textit{\textbf{V\char"0306}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this observation suggests that Linux Libertine O is at fault -- do you know whether than font is maintained?

Comment: @John I believe that development of Linux Libertine is stalled, one of the reasons why Libertinus was started.