# TikZ 3.0.0 (release) produces strange shadings if used with XeLaTeX and standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, standalone

I would like to use shadings in my TikZ graphics together with the `standalone` package and XeLaTeX, but for some reason it is broken if I try with the new 3.0.0 release ([download here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%203.0.0/)). Any other combination I tried works for me (use for example `article` class/`pdflatex`/`lualatex`/`TikZ` 2.10).

(I'm using a fully updated TeX Live 2013.)

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass{article} % would work

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[top color=red] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

### Expected Output

[image: expected output]

### Question

How can I avoid the problem and which package/class is causing it?

Comment: It is XeLaTeX that is failing to support the shadings properly.  I don't know the current situation but this is a known problem.

Comment: @percusse for some reason I have no problem with `2.10`.

Comment: You are right, I should maybe say that XeLaTeX is not providing the correct PDF literals in some cases. I will try to find a similar question where 2.10 also fails. But also depends on he wiever.

Comment: @percusse Thx for the info. Quite Evil bugs around. Looks like I can't use LuaLatex (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28733/lualatex-protrusion-problem-with-negative-value) nor XeLaTex. Back to pdfLaTex ;(

Comment: and interesting that it won't fail with with the `article` class. Must be some (un)funny bug.

Comment: What version of `standalone` are you using? Could you try it again with the `preview` class option and then again with the `crop` option and tell me what happens.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Version `2012/09/15 v1.1b`. The options `preview` and `crop` aren't changing the output.

Comment: @someonr I notice you added a bounty to the LuaTeX question you linked to. I'm not sure it can do much good: actual bugs are tricky to fix from the StackExchange end, particularly when they are in the binaries. On the positive side, I may be on the trail of the cause of this bug, and think I may have a solution 'in hand'.

Comment: @JosephWright I knew that StackExchange isn't the best place for this. But I thought that it would raise some attention to this old bug and after all here are quite a few developers (including you). In worst case I loose 100 rep for nothing ;)

Comment: @MartinScharrer I also continue to experience the shade/XeLaTeX problem only with `standalone` (2012/09/15 v1.1b) under MikTeX. Any news since the question was asked (one year ago) ?

Comment: @JosephWright Is there any update on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I confirm that this is a regression and I can reproduce it.

PGF 3.0.0 comes with a lot of changes around shading and xelatex. These changes activate the full feature set of fadings, shadings, etc. just as pdflatex does. The fact that it works only for particular document classes is a bad surprise.

---

**EDIT**

I fixed the bug in the developer version of PGF; will become part of the next stable.

The candidate can be downloaded at http://pgf.sourceforge.net/

---

The following is probably better suited for a ticketing system, but since I started looking into the bug, I can document my steps here as well. Perhaps some expert on low-level drivers jumps onto it.

I found that it is caused by the code resulting from `\pgfsys@vertshading`, more specifically, the resulting PDF code segment

```
7 0 obj 
<<
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 72 -72]
/Subtype /Form
/Length 15
/Resources 8 0 R
/FormType 1
/Type /XObject
/BBox [-72 72 28 172]
>>
stream
 0 G 0 g /Sh sh
endstream
```

PGF 2.10 produced a further negative transformation (the part with `1 0 0 1.. cm`).

```
<<
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 72 -72]
/Subtype /Form
/Length 37
/Resources 7 0 R
/FormType 1
/Type /XObject
/BBox [-72 72 28 172]
>>
stream
 0 G 0 g q 1 0 0 1 -72 72 cm /Sh sh Q
endstream
```

I have patched the resulting pdf manually; if I introduce these negative shifts, the result is correct. Alternatively, If I patch `/Matrix` and `/BBox` to

```
7 0 obj 
<<
/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]
/Subtype /Form
/Length 15
/Resources 8 0 R
/FormType 1
/Type /XObject
/BBox [0 0 100 100]
>>
stream
 0 G 0 g /Sh sh
endstream
```

it works as well. Interestingly, the value `100 100` is available as size in `\pgfsys@vertshading`; it is the bounding box in pgf's coordinates somewhere deep down in the system. I experimented a while but got no grip on the problem; I do not know how the "72" enters here.

Note that pdflatex generates the `0 0 100 100` as bounding box with identity matrix (the correct one). Using the `article` class and `xelatex` also produces this value.

Perhaps some guru on device driver development can shed some light on it; I bet it is related to something deep in the latex-specific pgfutil stuff (`pgfutil-latex.def`).

Comment: @heikooberdiek I would appreciate any hints - perhaps you see it right-away.

Comment: not sure if this is related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33260/tikz-example-involving-spies-wont-typeset-properly-using-xelatex, but the spy feature is now working with xetex