# Is it possible to use TikZ shading with XeLaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, color

When adding the second solution to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252901/), I initially tried to compile with XeLaTeX so that I could use `fontspec`. However, that didn't work, although compiling with LuaLaTeX did.

I've now managed to create an MnWE: there is a problem, it seems with my use of `inner color` and `outer color` with the XeTeX engine. The following example gives the expected output when compiled with pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, but not XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [inner color=yellow, outer color=red] {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output with LuaLaTeX and pdfLaTeX:

[image: sunset node]

Output with XeLaTeX:

[image: sunless node]

Is it possible to use this kind of fill with XeLaTeX? If so, how? If not, is any engine-agnostic alternative available?

Comment: It is a problem with standalone see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151524/tikz-3-0-0-release-produces-strange-shadings-if-used-with-xelatex-and-standalo  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249624/shadings-fadings-apparent-bug-in-tikz

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. It is so difficult to find duplicates - I really did look because I had a vague idea that I'd actually *read* a question about this myself. But I still couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Tikz 3.0.0 when used with Standalone and shadings will fail to work.

I had asked a similar question to yours, see [Shadings/fadings (apparent) bug in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249624/4778), then subsequently I decided to [file a bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/363/) and this is the response from Christian Feuersänger:

> Thanks for the report.
>
> The issue has been solved already and I confirmed that it works. I also confirmed that it fails to work with PGF 3.0.0 .
> You will have to wait for the next PGF release.

In the meantime, you can use the solution provided by Heiko to my question.