# How to Give Stars a Glow Effect

Tags: xetex, pstricks, pspicture, picture-mode, psvectorian

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

% % % Compiled with Xelatex

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,12)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{blue}%

\psframe[fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=solid](-5,-5)(5,12) %Used with colored frame 
\psframe[linecolor=blue](-5,-5)(5,12)% draws frame in black.
%top and bottom center

\large

\rput(0,3){\textbf{\scalebox{0.92}{\textcolor{white}{HOW TO MAKE THE STARS GLOW?}}}}

\rput(0,9.25){\color{white}{\huge{\textbf{*}}}}
\rput(0.03,9.25){\color{white}{\huge{\textbf{*}}}}
\rput(-2.25,5.75){\color{white}{\huge{\textbf{*}}}}
\rput(-2.25,5.75){\color{white}{\huge{\textbf{*}}}}
\rput(3.25,7){\color{white}{\huge{\textbf{*}}}}
\rput(3.25,7){\color{white}{\huge{\textbf{*}}}}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I have used doubly-imprinted asterisks to produce the stars. (Might there be a better way?)

QUESTION: How may I produce a ``glow'' effect around the stars?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an idea using `tikz` and `fadings`. The command `\glowstar[<size>]{x,y}` called inside a `tikzpicture` will make a glowing star at the given coordinates.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, calc}
\tikzfading[name=dim fade, inner color=transparent!50, outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=bright fade, right color=transparent!100, left color=transparent!100, middle color=transparent!0]

\newcommand{\glowstar}[2][.5]{\fill[white,path fading=dim fade](#2)circle[radius=#1*.4];
    \foreach \t in {0,60,120}{
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.02*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.02*#1)$)--cycle;
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.3*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.04*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.3*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.04*#1)$)--cycle;}
    \fill[white] (#2)circle[radius=#1*.075];
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue] rectangle (4,2);
\glowstar[.5]{2,1}
\glowstar[.2]{1,1.5}
\glowstar[.3]{3,.5}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is quite nice!

Comment: Is there a way to generate these stars when compiling with `xelatex`? When I incorporate your code in conjunction with my `pspicture` code, and compile it with `xelatex` (as I must do) in the actual document---the "glow" disappears. Thanks again.

Comment: @mlchristians: I'm not an expert with `pstricks`, so I don't know if it supports some version of `fadings`, but you can use `TikZ` with `XeLaTeX`. Can you switch the rest of the diagram to `TikZ`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I must compile the document in question with `xelatex`.

Comment: @mlchristians: It's no problem using `TikZ` with `XeLaTeX`. Is there a reason you can't use `TikZ` for your star diagram?

Comment: Yes, because it does not produce the glowing effect that results when I compile your code with `lualatex`.  I expect that the same glowing effect would result with `pdflatex` as well. If you compile your code with `Xelatex`, are you able to produce the same output you posted? If so, then the problem would most definitely be on my end, I would say.

Comment: Yes. `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX` both produce the correct output. Are you using an old installation of PGF? See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151524/125871).

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to check and for providing the helpful link. Now I know the problem is on my end.

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise. If you can't figure it out you should post another question. There are definitely experts on this site who can help.