Encoding Glowing Stars into a Tikzpicture with Fadings
The following code is based on the answer of @Tom posted here: Extending the Features of the Glowing Star Posted by User Sandy G
which produces:

I would like to add some of these glowing stars into a tikzpicture with fading along the lines of the last picture produced by @hpekristiansen found here: Adding Multiple Titles with Gilded Effects
To this end, consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4.375in,paperheight=7.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,calc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{yfonts}


\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}


\tikzfading[name=dim fade, inner color=transparent!40, outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=bright fade, right color=transparent!100, left color=transparent!100, middle color=transparent!0]

\newcommand{\glowstar}[3][.5]{\fill[white,path fading=dim fade](#2)circle[radius=#1*.6];
    \foreach \t in {0,60,120}{
        \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.05*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.02*#1)$)--cycle;
        \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.04*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.04*#1)$)--cycle;
    }
    \foreach \l [count=\n from 0] in {#3}{
        \fill[rotate around={\n*90:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(\l*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(.4,.06*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.4,.06*#1)$)--cycle;
    }        
    \fill[white] (#2)circle[radius=#1*.13];
}



\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mypage, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
    \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
    \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
    \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
    \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
    \node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
    \node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
        
    \node [anchor=south] (n1) at ([yshift=133pt]current page text area) {\begin{tikzpicture}{\glowstar[0.75]{8,10}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}}\end{tikzpicture}};
    
    \node [anchor=south] (n2) at ([yshift=85pt,xshift=-75pt]current page text area) {\begin{tikzpicture}{\glowstar[0.55]{8,10}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}}\end{tikzpicture}};
    
    
    \node [anchor=south] (n2) at ([yshift=85pt,xshift=75pt]current page text area) {\begin{tikzpicture}{\glowstar[0.55]{8,10}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}}\end{tikzpicture}};
    
    \node [anchor=south] (n3) at ([yshift=5pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{1.75}{Starry, Starry}}};
    
    \node [anchor=south] (n4) at ([yshift=-50pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{1.75}{Night}}};
    
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \fill[black!75!blue] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
        %shadows
        \fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}, even odd rule] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east) (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east) (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east) ;
        \fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east);
        %add ball shading for each area
        \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=black!65] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        
        \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=white] (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east);
        
        \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=white] (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east);
        
        \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=PureGold] (n3.south west) rectangle (n3.north east);
        
        \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=PureGold] (n4.south west) rectangle (n4.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}

which produces the output:

I have likely not encoded the stars properly into the tikzpicure, as it seems to me that the glowing effect is not as well-defined as it is in the very first image.
QUESTION: How may I properly encode the glowing stars into the MWE (that is, using tikzpagenodes) so that each star "glows" as robustly as it appears in the first image?
I compile the code with lualatex.
Thank you.

You have two n2s in different places.

Oh, I missed it. Nesting tikzpictures isn't supported. Sometimes it works by chance, but otherwise you have to know exactly what you're doing. So doing the \begin{tikzpicture} thing inside a tikzpicture is pretty much inevitably going to break something this complex.

Don't try to nest tikzpictures unless you really know what you're doing, in which case you will know to almost never nest them and only ever as a last resort. Anything at all complicated is likely to break.
Fortunately, you don't need to do this. All you really want to do, as I understand it, is to add the stars. You don't want to fade or shade them. You want to pluck them from one sky and plop them into another. So just add them at the end.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721894/ 
% addaswyd o atebion (gweler isod)
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4.375in,paperheight=7.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,calc}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}
\tikzfading[name=dim fade, inner color=transparent!40, outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=bright fade, right color=transparent!100, left color=transparent!100, middle color=transparent!0]

\newcommand{\glowstar}[3][.5]{\fill[white,path fading=dim fade](#2)circle[radius=#1*.6];
  \foreach \t in {0,60,120}{
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.05*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.02*#1)$)--cycle;
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.04*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.04*#1)$)--cycle;
  }
  \foreach \l [count=\n from 0] in {#3}{
    \fill[rotate around={\n*90:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(\l*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(.4,.06*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.4,.06*#1)$)--cycle;
  }        
  \fill[white] (#2)circle[radius=#1*.13];
}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mypage, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
  \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
  \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
  \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
  \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
  \node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
  \node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
  \node [anchor=south] (n3) at ([yshift=5pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{1.75}{Starry, Starry}}};
  \node [anchor=south] (n4) at ([yshift=-50pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{1.75}{Night}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \fill[black!75!blue] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
  \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=black!65] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
  \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=PureGold] (n3.south west) rectangle (n3.north east);
  \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=PureGold] (n4.south west) rectangle (n4.north east);
  \coordinate (a) at ([yshift=133pt+1.75cm]current page text area);
  \coordinate (b) at ([yshift=85pt+1.375cm,xshift=-75pt]current page text area);
  \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=85pt+1.375cm,xshift=75pt]current page text area);
  \glowstar[0.75]{a}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}
  \glowstar[0.55]{b}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}
  \glowstar[0.55]{c}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


If I've inadvertently removed fadings you wanted in the picture, you can add those back, provided you don't use tikzpictures inside other tikzpictures, but you would need to add some kind of explicit sizing to compensate for the lack of content in the nodes, in order to get the sizing right.
[Edit 2 was just the output of the OP's code for comparison.]
Edit 3
To address the question not originally asked, to combine the code from the two linked questions, you just need to add the stars at the end. It is the same principle as above.

\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4.375in,paperheight=7.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,calc}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
\definecolor{PureGold}{RGB}{255,215,0}
\usepackage{yfonts}

% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721771/
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mypage, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
  \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
  \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
  \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
  \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
  \node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
  \node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
  \node [anchor=south] (n1) at ([yshift=133pt]current page text area)  {};
  \node [anchor=south] (n5) at ([yshift=85pt,xshift=-75pt]current page text area) {};
  \node [anchor=south] (n2) at ([yshift=85pt,xshift=75pt]current page text area) {};
  \node [anchor=south] (n3) at ([yshift=5pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{1.75}{Starry, Starry}}};
  \node [anchor=south] (n4) at ([yshift=-50pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{1.75}{Night}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643846/how-to-give-stars-a-glow-effect
\tikzfading[name=dim fade, inner color=transparent!40, outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzfading[name=bright fade, right color=transparent!100, left color=transparent!100, middle color=transparent!0]
\newcommand{\glowstar}[3][.5]{\fill[white,path fading=dim fade](#2)circle[radius=#1*.6];
  \foreach \t in {0,60,120}{
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.05*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.9*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.02*#1)$)--cycle;
    \fill[rotate around={\t:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(0,.04*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.5*#1,0)$)--($(#2)+(0,.04*#1)$)--cycle;
  }
  \foreach \l [count=\n from 0] in {#3}{
    \fill[rotate around={\n*90:(#2)}, white,path fading=bright fade]($(#2)-(\l*#1,0)$)--($(#2)-(.4,.06*#1)$)--($(#2)+(.4,.06*#1)$)--cycle;
  }        
  \fill[white] (#2)circle[radius=#1*.13];
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \fill[black!75!blue] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
  %shadows
  \fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}, even odd rule] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east) (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east) (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east) ;
  \fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east);
  \fill[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-1.35pt}]  (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east);
  %add ball shading for each area
  \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
  \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n1.south west) rectangle (n1.north east);
  \shade[path fading=mypage, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n2.south west) rectangle (n2.north east);
  \coordinate (a) at ([yshift=133pt+1.75cm]current page text area);
  \coordinate (b) at ([yshift=85pt+1.375cm,xshift=-75pt]current page text area);
  \coordinate (c) at ([yshift=85pt+1.375cm,xshift=75pt]current page text area);
  \glowstar[0.75]{a}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}
  \ifdefined\firststars
    \glowstar[0.55]{b}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}
    \glowstar[0.55]{c}{1.1,1.8,1.1,1.1}
  \fi
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\firststars{hi}}%
\makeatother
\end{document}

The conditional inclusion of the second and third star is necessary to avoid exceeding TeX's maximum dimension on the first run (or if the .aux is missing). So there is only one star on first compilation. This is not noticeable because it takes two runs to get things in the right place anyway, so, as it happens, none of the three is visible on the first run. Nonetheless, one of them is there (off the page), while the other two are not.
Edit 4
Here's another version which it just occurred to me might be what you're getting at.

To get this version, I just added
\clip  (n3.north) -- ++(5cm,0pt) arc (0:180:5.15cm) -- cycle;

before the code for the stars. This limits the effect of the shadings used to colour the stars, but I'm not sure it actually has any impact in this case because the fading of the stars is a path fading anyway.
Edit 6
Another possibility is to use the PureGold colour with the code from the linked answer (which makes the ornaments far clearer) in order to get a yellower effect. There are different shades of gold, so there's obviously a range here.

Always assuming you don't want silver, of course, to match the stars ....


I think you might want the first of the star shadings back, for instance, because it probably affects the shading on the title. But I'm not sure if that interaction was intentional or otherwise?

@DDS I can't see those in the MWE you posted in the question either.

@DDS See edit above. The lower picture is the result of compiling the code you posted. The higher picture is the result of compiling my answer. The ornaments at the bottom are extremely dark in both and the upper ones really don't look gilded either, though they are a bit more visible.

It would be helpful if you post the code which produces the second picture and remove the code (and picture) of the first. Many thanks.

@DDS I've posted another version which combines the gilded ornaments/title from the green cover with the content of the blue cover and adds the stars in the same way as in my original answer. I thought you meant this when you left the comments before, but your query about the second image now has me really confused as the code for that was not mine at all. I only posted it for comparison. It was just copy-pasted from your question.

Note to third party readers: the current answer removes what @DDS refers to as the second picture. The code for that can be found in the question, together with the OP's image of the result. What is now the second picture above is the third and the second lot of code is the code for that image (and the second lot of code I've posted, as opposed to merely compiled). Hopefully that's all crystal clear ;).
