# Tikz (spy and background) libraries with etex and pgfplots packages in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, backgrounds, e-tex, spy

I am working at a quite complicated beamer presentation and at some point I could not manage to use the `\spy` command of `TikZ` as desired.

Trying to reproduce the problem, I came up with the following one-frame example (copying an example of the spy library from section 68.1 of the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, decorations.fractals, spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[spy using overlays={size=12mm}]
        \draw [decoration=Koch snowflake] decorate { decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (2,0) }}}};
        \spy [green,magnification=3] on (0.6,0.1) in node at (-0.3,-1);
        \spy [blue,magnification=5] on (1,0.5) in node at (1,-1);
        \spy [red,magnification=10] on (1.6,0.1) in node at (2.3,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compiled as such, the magnified regions do not show anything but the coloured background.

Playing around with this code, I noticed that *any* of the following modifications solves the problem:

- Put the `\usepackage{pgfplots}` line after the `\usetikzlibrary` one;
- Comment out the `\usepackage{etex}` line;
- Do not load the `backgrounds` library;
- Load the `backgrounds` library as last one.

Clearly, the last possibility is well suited for my problem (and I already adopted it for my presentation), but I would like to get a better understanding of what is going on in the code above.

1. Which *role* do the packages `etex` and `pgfplots` play in the game?
2. Why, in presence of such a packages, loading the `backgrounds` library before the `spy` one causes the magnified regions to disappear?
3. More in general, why do the order of `TikZ` libraries in the `\usetikzlibrary` can matter? I would naively guess that it should not be the case.

Searching around before posting the question, I discovered [in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78366/128737) a bit about how layers work, but this did not answer exactly my questions.

**Clarification:**

To produce the single frame in my example, the packages `etex` and `pgfplots`, as well as the `backgrounds` library, are not needed. However, I need them in my presentation.

Comment: Usually [tag:pgfplots] ruins things by turning on FPU. The only appearance of eTeX in the manual is about `\pgfkeysifdefined`. Packages [tag:spy] and [tag:backgrounds] both defines the style `execute at begin scope` and they may overwrite each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer and pgfplots are less relevant to this problem. Here is how it goes wrong

- Beamer, pgfplots, and Ti*k*Z will include PGF, which will include `pgfcorelayers.code.tex`.
- `pgfcorelayers.code.tex` has

  > ```
  > \let\pgf@newbox=\newbox
  > ```
- eTeX has

  > ```
  > \def\newbox{\alloc@4\box\chardef\insc@unt}
  > ```
- `backgrounds` has

  > ```
  > \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
  > ```

  this is essentially

  > ```
  > \pgf@newbox\pgf@layerbox@background 
  > \pgf@newbox\pgf@layerboxsaved@background
  > ```
- `spy` has

  > ```
  > \newbox\tikz@lib@spybox
  > ```

Notice that at this point, `\pgf@newbox` is different from `\newbox`. And it turns out that `\tikz@lib@spybox` is the same as `\pgf@layerboxsaved@background`. So potentially an action on the background layer will clean up the spy box.

## Why `\tikz@lib@spybox` = `\pgf@layerboxsaved@background`?

In TeX, there are only 255 box register and they are called `\box0` through `\box255`. This is extremely user-unfriendly. So in plain-TeX, Knuth defined a syntax `\newbox\mybox`. It works as follows:

- `\count14` will count how many boxed are there;
- `\newbox` will add `\count14` by one, and let `\mybox` be `\count14`.

**However** there is a discrepancy between **add and assign** and **assign and add**. This is pretty much like in C language

```
mybox = count14++;
```

is different from

```
mybox = ++count14;
```

So one should make sure that both `\pgf@newbox` and `\newbox` choose the same way.

By the way: Box register assignment is by default (maybe) printed into the 
log file. If you check the log file you will see something like

```
\tikz@lib@spybox=\box38
\pgf@layerboxsaved@background=\box38
```

and you will know something goes wrong.

## Some workaround

- If you put eTeX before Ti*k*Z and pgfplots, both `\pgf@newbox` and `\newbox` will be the same and there is no problem. **However**, this does not work if Beamer calls PGF at the first place.
- If you put eTeX after Ti*k*Z and pgfplots, both `\pgf@newbox` and `\newbox` will be the same and there is no problem. **However**, this does not work if you declare any box using `\newbox` after eTeX is included.
- If you put `spy` before `backgrounds`, then the spy box is different from the background box. **However**, if you declare any box after `backgrounds` using `\newbox`, it will be the same as the background box.
- A safe way, to the best of my plain-TeX knowledge, is to include eTeX as early as possible and immediately reassign `\let\pgf@newbox=\newbox` again.

Comment: Wow, nice explanation! This required me to deepen more than expected. However, it is still not clear to me why you say that it turns out that `\tikz@lib@spybox` is the same as `\pgf@layerboxsaved@background`. If `\pgf@newbox` is (by accident) different from `\newbox`, I would guess that the spy box is different from the background one.

Comment: I agree to the OP: Nice explanation. As I am no expert in this: Do you consider this behavior being a bug and if yes, do you maybe also have an idea how that could be fixed?

Comment: The add-on of information was very useful. Just a minor clarification for less expert people like me. The definition of `\newbox` in `etex` looks identical to that in plain-TeX, but the `\alloc@` macro changes! So, in plain-TeX, `\count14` is incremented and then used, while, in `etex`, `\count14` is first used and then incremented.

Comment: About the suggestion of restoring `\let\pgf@newbox=\newbox` by hand, clearly it works. Inspired by your suggestion, I guessed that a `\RequirePackage{etex}` before the `\documentclass` statement could fix the problem in my code and it does.
Is this one of the special cases mentioned in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19926/128737)?